# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack error in Python

Tags: php, python, hadoop

Today I tried to execute the following command in Linux, I want to test the Streaming interface in hadoop,

```
 cat test.txt|php wc_mapper.php|python Reducer.py
```

an error happened:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Reducer.py", line 7, in <module>
word,count = line.split()   
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
"
```

the content of test.txt is as follows:

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

the content of wc_mapper.php which is written by PHP is

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$word2count = array();
while (($line = fgets(STDIN)) !== false) {
      $line = trim($line);
      $words = preg_split('/\W/', $line, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
      foreach ($words as $word) {
                echo $word, chr(9), "1", PHP_EOL;
      }
}
?>
```

and the content of Reducer.py which is written by Python is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from operator import itemgetter
import sys
word2count = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
   line = line.strip()
   word,count = line.split()
   try:
      count = int(count)
      word2count[word] = word2count.get(word, 0) + count
   except ValueError:
      pass

sorted_word2count = sorted(word2count.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
for word,count in sorted_word2count:
   print '%s\t%s'%(word,count)
```

who knows the reason of the error, how to fix this issue?
when I execute the first part command

```
cat test.txt|php wc_mapper.php|sort
```

, I got the following output:

```
hello   1
hello   1
hello   1
world   1
world   1
world   1
```

the first line is null, but it occupy one line.

Comment: Is the output of the PHP script what you expect? Take off the last pipe and see what you get: `cat test.txt|php wc_mapper.php`

Comment: Pls see my edit. Is that the null line which causes the error?

Comment: @Coinnigh Yes, it is. After the `strip()` you could add: `if not line: continue`

Comment: @Riaz,  Any other method? How can stop the null line from output please?

Comment: Maybe check `test.txt` for empty lines, and get rid of those?

Answer (score 0):

Provide delimiter in `split()` function

```
   try:    
        word,count = line.split(" ") 
   except:
        print("Error")
```

I have put single space as delimiter. you can change accordingly.

Comment: It does not work, also "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
" error. How can I stop the first null line from output?

Comment: what is the value of "line" before the split() function call?

Comment: It comes from the output of "cat test.txt|php wc_mapper.php|sort",

Comment: please put print(line) and check the output.

Comment: I think the null line comes from the code "echo $word, chr(9), "1", PHP_EOL;" , how can we stop the first null line from output?

Comment: check for you delimiter before split() function. For example, if(line.count(' ')>0):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113550/discussion-between-coinnigh-and-vivek).